# Gettting user join request list with python-telegram-bot

Tags: telegram, python-telegram-bot

I am building a telegram bot.
I want to know whether my bot is able to get the users detail who have sent a join request to my group in a form of list.

If not, is there any other methods that I can use?

Answer (score 1):

In case you haven't figured it out yet

```
def Demo_get_join_requests(): 
     chat_id = ChatID 
     bot = telegram.Bot(Token) 
     results=bot.get_updates(ChatID, allowed_updates=['chat_join_request']) 
     List-of-users = []
     for x in results: 
        List-of-users.append(x.from_user)
     Print(List-of-users)
```